# How to handle redundant files in SVN?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I am using SVN for my project to track the changes. I am using TortoiseSVN as a client. Recently I removed some files from the project which I no longer need, however these files are still inside the SVN repository. I want to check in latest changes but I don't want the unwanted files to appear whenever I do SVN Update. How do I handle this situation? What are the best practices here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use SVN Delete (right-click, TortoiseSVN-> Delete in a default configuration) to remove files properly. Then commit the changes. The deleted files should appear as Missing in the Commit dialog if you don't do this, and at this point you can select the files and that will delete them as well.

https://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-rename.html